# How to call the lambda stored in pointer to the `std::function`?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function, function-call

I have a pointer to `std::function` that stores lambda inside.
How can I call that lambda?

example:

```
std::function <void()>* fx = new std::function <void()>([] {std::cout << "Hello world;\n"; });
    //here i need to call my fx, just fx(); does not works in this case
```

`fx` may be stored inside `std::pair`

Comment: `(*fx)();` But why are you using a pointer to std::function. Seems like a bad choice.

Comment: @super An answer should go to the answer box. Please...

Comment: Read some [good C++ programming](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Prefer [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) to raw ones

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call it either of the following ways:

1. Dereferencing the pointer and call

   ```
   (*fx)();
   ```
2. or explicitly calling the
   [`std::function<R(Args...)>::operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator())

   ```
   fx->operator()();  // explicitly calling the `operator()`
   ```
3. or using
   [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)

   ```
   std::invoke(*fx); // needed C++17 or later
   ```

However, you should be re-think about using a pointer to the `std::function`, which is normally not required.

---

> `fx` may be stored inside `std::pair`

This does not actually matter, as you need to first get the pair's element (i.e. `pair.first` or `pair.second`) and call the stored lambda, as mentioned above. For instance, if the `pair.second` is your `fx`

```
(*pair.second)();
```